# Reading Data from a sound file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, processing

I am trying to read data from a .wav file from position X to Y specified by user. The code compiles file but for some reason the wavread function is not reading from the specified positions. It returns zero in the `y` vector. If I don't do like `[y,fs]=wavread('Kalimba.wav', [StartingTime EndingTime]);` , then the code works fine and returns non zero data.

Why is this happening and how can I solve this?

Here is the code:

```
 function PlayFromXtoY(StartingTime,EndingTime)

% converting the startingTime and EndingTime to minutes

if StartingTime == 0
    disp('Zero')
    StartingTime=1;

elseif StartingTime < 1
         disp('Start <1')
         StartingTime=StartingTime*10;

    elseif StartingTime >= 1
            disp('Start >=1');
            StartingTime=StartingTime*60;
end

if EndingTime < 1
    disp('End <1');
    EndingTime=EndingTime*10;

elseif EndingTime >= 1
        disp('End >=1');
        EndingTime=EndingTime*60;
end

[y,fs]=wavread('Kalimba.wav', [StartingTime EndingTime]); % returning 0 in y for some reason

wavplay(y,fs);
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is that you perform very strange modifications of your start time and stop time before you invoke `wavread`. It could help to `disp` those times just before the call and if hese really make sense.

Most importantly, however, you consider these limits as times while to `wavread` they are not. According to he documentation, the limits you pass are supposed to be sample numbers.